# How to customize colors in maven 3.5 console output

Tags: maven, console

Maven 3.5.0 introduces coloring in console output.

It's a cool feature, however I don't like some default color choices, for example intensive blue INFO looks too distracting.

Is it possible to customize colors somehow?

Answer (score 18):

Turns out it is possible.

Maven uses [several styles](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/maven/shared/tags/maven-shared-utils-3.1.0/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/shared/utils/logging/Style.java) to format its output:

```java
enum Style
{

    DEBUG(   "bold,cyan"   ),
    INFO(    "bold,blue"   ),
    WARNING( "bold,yellow" ),
    ERROR(   "bold,red"    ),
    SUCCESS( "bold,green"  ),
    FAILURE( "bold,red"    ),
    STRONG(  "bold"        ),
    MOJO(    "green"       ),
    PROJECT( "cyan"        );
...
}
```

You can override the default color of a style with the system property `style.style_name`. For example to change the style of INFO from default blue to dark gray you pass

`-Dstyle.info=bold,black`

option to maven. It also can be specified with `MAVEN_OPTS` environment variable in order not to type it on every maven invocation.

If you don't know which style is used in the particular part of output, you can match it by its default color.

The colors that can be used in a style are defined by [jansi](https://github.com/fusesource/jansi/blob/jansi-1.x/jansi/src/main/java/org/fusesource/jansi/Ansi.java#L33) library:

```java
public enum Color {
        BLACK(0, "BLACK"),
        RED(1, "RED"),
        GREEN(2, "GREEN"),
        YELLOW(3, "YELLOW"),
        BLUE(4, "BLUE"),
        MAGENTA(5, "MAGENTA"),
        CYAN(6, "CYAN"),
        WHITE(7, "WHITE"),
        DEFAULT(9, "DEFAULT");
}
```

Seems that you can prefix color with `bg` to specify the background color, and to make it intensive, you add `bold` modifier, for example:
`bold,white,bgcyan` — intensive white on cyan background.

Comment: You wouldn't by any chance know how to change the default output, currently printed in white?

Answer (score 0):

When using maven inside Netbeans 8 the `-D` settings from the accepted answer won't work.

Solution: in the menu go to "Tools", "Options", in the Dialog to "Miscellaneus", "Output". On the right you'll see "Debug", "Warning", "Failure", "Success" and you can change the colors there. I used this to change the hard-to-see orange to a darker color.